# How to switch between maven and local build dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

My title isn't exactly clear so I'll describe my situation before asking the question:

I have a number of libraries (~15), some of which depend on each other and a number of apps (~5) that depend on various subsets of these libraries. The libraries are hosted on an internal maven site. Most of these apps function within the same domain and there's an overlap in functionalities as well as data models used. Sometimes, adding a feature means making changes to a library in the middle of the hierarchy tree, providing support for it upstream (libs towards the root of the dependency tree), and then utilizing the changes upstream (applications as well as libraries that use the changed libraries).

I want to:

- Fetch these libraries from Maven when I'm working on application code
- Edit and compile these libraries from within my project while I'm working on changes that affect libraries

My current process is a bit tedious:

1. Checkout the source for the library(ies) and place it beside my application code (`workspace/app_code`, `workspace/lib1_code`, `workspace/lib2_code`, etc.)
2. I add `include ':lib1_code'`, `include ':lib2_code'`, etc. to my `settings.gradle` (I have these commented out so I just toggle them on and off as needed)
3. I replace the
   `implementation "com.packages:lib1:1.2.3"` with `implementation project(':lib1_code')` (and so on)
4. I do the same in the dependent libraries too.

As you can see, it's a lot of work and nobody on my team (myself included) likes the process.
I want to be able to just do all of the above with a set of properties like `buildLib1UseLocal=true`

Questions:

1. How common is my scenario?
2. Does gradle have support for something like this?
3. Is there another build system that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is based on Groovy, so it provides full scripting support. You can just evaluate the property on your own:

```
dependencies {
    if (buildLib1UseLocal) {
        implementation project(':lib1_code')
    } else {
        implementation 'com.packages:lib1:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

Gradle even provides a feature called [**dependency substitutions**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:dependency_substitution_rules). It allows you to define your dependencies in the regular way, but to resolve them from other sources:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.packages:lib1:1.2.3'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        if (buildLib1UseLocal) {
             substitute module('com.packages:lib1:1.2.3') with project(':lib1_code') because '<some reason>'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have to replicate this code in all the library codes too, right?
The good thing, though, would be that if App A includes libs 1, 2, 3, the dependency substitution will propagate to the libs too (whichever is built locally), correct?

Comment: As always, you may wrap some piece of Gradle configuration inside a `allprojects` closure of your root project to apply it for all projects at one place.